# LaTeX tabu package breaks Vim spell and syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, spell-checking

The first line of this section of LaTeX code breaks syntax highlighting and spell check whenever I scroll to the area of the document that contains it:

```
\begin{tabu} {*3{X[l$]}}
    col1    & col2  & col3
\end{tabu}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: Example of what the synax parsing problem looks like]

As you can tell I'm using the [(excellent) packet tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu), and it's when I apply the column descriptor multiplier that things goes astray. It does not happen until I get that part of the document into the view port, so if I start at the end of the file it is fine until I get to that line (182 in my example image). The moment that line goes into view, everything bellow it is bogus.

It looks like there is some problem with the curly braces, which are marked... But I have no idea where to get from here.

Cheers.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the `$` symbol, which starts an inline math environment.

Comment: Oh, that could actually be so. There is another way of writing the same expression — I'll try that tomorrow and report back.

Comment: `tabu` is out-dated, buggy and will not be developed or fixed in the future (official statement of the maintainer).

Comment: Happen to have a link?